# strictly positive solution to $Ax=b$

Tags: equation-solving, system-variables

How to find in mathematica one real strictly positive solution, if any, of $Ax=b$. A is rectangular matrix.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See `LinearSolve[]` and then `FindInstance[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
b = {6, 4};

Reduce[{a.{x, y, z} == b, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
(* 0<x<4 && y == 2 && z == 4-x *)
```

Find one instance:

```
FindInstance[{a.{x, y, z} == {6, 4}, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
(* {{x -> 2,y -> 2,z -> 2}} *)
```

Find three instances:

```
FindInstance[{a.{x, y, z} == {6, 4}, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals, 3]
(*  {{x -> 31/76, y -> 2, z -> 273/76}, 
     {x -> 33/76, y -> 2, z -> 271/76}, 
     {x -> 267/76, y -> 2, z -> 37/76}} *)
```